# Does scrolling bring an element out of focus and trigger onBlur event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events

I am creating a page using React where I have multiple videos embedded. I want the video playback to be paused whenever the video goes out of viewport. As a first instinct, I tried the `onBlur` event in the video tag but my handler just wasn't called. I looked up various links and I found that people had handled the same by using the `pageYOffset` property of window.
I was able to do it using `pageYOffset` but I am unable to understand as to why the `onBlur` event handler wasn't called when the video moves out of viewport.

```
<video ref="vidRef" onBlur = {console.log("Blur called")} onPlay={() => this.hidePlayButton()} onPause={() => this.showPlayButton()} onClick={() => this.showPlayButton()} onEnded={() => this.showPlayButton()}>
          <source type="video/mp4" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0" src={this.props.hpVideoSrc}/>
      </video>
```

On trying the above code snippet I could see the output on console. But as soon as I replaced the console command with my handler like this,

```
<video ref="vidRef" onBlur={() => this.handleOnBlur()} onPlay={() => this.hidePlayButton()} onPause={() => this.showPlayButton()} onClick={() => this.showPlayButton()} onEnded={() => this.showPlayButton()}>
          <source type="video/mp4" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0" src={this.props.hpVideoSrc}/>
      </video>
```

It just didn't work. The `onBlur` handler wasn't called. I want to know what are the conditions for `onBlur` event to be called for a video element. Is it triggered when I scroll the video out of view?

I could see the conditions for `onBlur` in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp). Are these the only conditions for the event to be called? I am a beginner with HTML/CSS and JS so I don't have an in-depth understanding of the events.

Comment: onBlur is normally used for input fields, So you should try onmouseout (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp), but I would suggest you to have a DOM event added which monitors scrolling and performs some checkings every time it is triggered in order to find out if style properties offsetLeft and offsetTop are out of view.

Comment: Please, note that some events may not work as expected. Specially comparing between browsers, specially in explorer/edge.

Comment: `onBlur={this.handleOnBlur()}` This makes it work. You just have to simply call the function. But for me the issue is, the event is triggering when the page loads. Not when the video goes out of the viewport

Comment: @IntrepidBlue could you give a brief idea on how did you do the task using `pageYOffset`?

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, for me handling the onmousedown event on a wrapper div element and preventingdefault actions worked.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault